# Flutter firebase hosting Error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'gCr')

Tags: flutter

After completing the firebase hosting without any errors, I went into the site and found this error, but I don't know the solution

this is the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'gCr')
at main.dart.js:43863:27
at ara.a (main.dart.js:5471:62)
at ara.$2 (main.dart.js:35989:14)
at aor.$1 (main.dart.js:35983:21)
at amc.ajB (main.dart.js:36791:34)
at amc.u2 (main.dart.js:36793:21)
at ajT.$0 (main.dart.js:36375:11)
at Object.x8 (main.dart.js:5584:40)
at a6.o3 (main.dart.js:36308:3)
at Rh.dq (main.dart.js:35978:8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well make sure the deploy folder is build/web plus

Answer (score 1):

I ran :

```
flutter clean -df
```

to delete the old build, then,

```
flutter pub get  
flutter build web --release
firebase deploy
```

and it worked.

Comment: I had the same issue. Reinstalling the dependencies worked for me.